# Picture box in asp

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie using asp.net is there other alternative for picture box there is no picturebox in asp. I just wanna use tool to store the loaded barcode on the picturebox please help me... Heres my code using picturebox in vb.net

```
pncode.image=Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeIamge(txtSting.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried Google?  First Result of the search [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14409/GenCode128-A-Code128-Barcode-Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14409/GenCode128-A-Code128-Barcode-Generator)

Comment: @Andreas Rohde  yes,sir it runs on the  winform ... I just wanna run it using webform thats why i'm asking about alter of picture box to seeand store that rendered image :)